# Eclipse preference page with multiple arrays

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, preferences

I tried to search the internet for examples for doing that, but can not find a good one. Also I checking eclipse IDE source code, but it's a bit too big to filter out what I need for an example.

What I would need is something similar to Eclipse File Association page below.

My plan is later to replace File types list with a combo and add more values/controls per combo selection.

I would be very thankful for an example or a link to an example that does that or has a same concept with working preference store.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the Google Eclipse plugin source code. I had to achieve something similar to your needs, and inspired myself from [there](http://google-plugin-for-eclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.core/src/com/google/appengine/eclipse/core/preferences/ui/GaePreferencePage.java). It is properly designed. You can take a look at the repository right [here](http://google-plugin-for-eclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/).

In my case, I needed checkboxes instead of combos, and used a CheckboxTableViewer from the JFace library, there are plenty of example onlines (e.g: [JFace snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets)).
As Alex said, first, works on Eclipse preferences concept... when you got it, it will just stay some pure UI tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that it is nothing more then simple preferences page with two `Lists` which just represents conformity between file types and editors.
The example how to implement your own preferences page is here: [Eclipse Preferences - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html)

If you want to have `Combo` - there is no problem - you just replace upper `ListEditor` woth your `ComboFieldEditor` and proceed with adding more conrols. The file associations are stored in Eclipse preferences and you can access them whenever you try to open some file to retrieve corresponding editor.